# Symfony2 Variable "name" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm new to Symfony, so this is most certain a simple mistake from my side.

I get the following error: Variable "worker" does not exist.

The template looks like this:

```
{% extends "NTSBSServiceBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Rapportera</h1>
    {% for worker in workers if workers %}
        {{ worker.name }}
    {% else %}
        <em>Det finns inga öppna protokoll för närvarande...</em>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the controller method look like this:

```
/**
 * List all open protocols, grouped by worker.
 * 
 * @Route("/", name="report")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $workers = $em->getRepository('NTSBSServiceBundle:Worker')->findAll();

    return array(
        'workers' => $workers,
    );

}
```

I have checked, and $workers does contain entities from the database. The twig gets rendered. If I remove the for-loop, naturally the error message disappears.

Hoping that someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE:

Have confirmed that the correct controller is used by exiting in indexAction(). If i do a print_r of $workers, I get the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker Object
    (
        [id:NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker:private] => 2
        [name:protected] => Worker 1
        [mail:protected] => worker1@example.com
        [phone:protected] => 123456789
    )

[1] => NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker Object
    (
        [id:NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker:private] => 3
        [name:protected] => Worker 2
        [mail:protected] => worker2@example.com
        [phone:protected] => 123456789
    )
)
```

Also I have tried to change the rendering-method by changing from annotation to using the render-method, as such:

```
return $this->render('NTSBSServiceBundle:Report:index.html.twig',array( 'workers' => $workers ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do `{% for i in x if x  %}`
You have to do

```
{% if x | length > 0 %}
  {% for i in x %}
    instructions
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Use twig doc : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc

Comment: I changed my code to look like that, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I do always loop through arrays in Twig like that:

```
{% for b in books %}
    {{ b.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% if not books %}
    <i>{% trans %}utils.nothing{% endtrans %}</i>
{% endif %}
```

But your error looks like a variable is missing. What is your error message?
*Symfony2 Variable “name” does not exist* 

or

*Variable "worker" does not exist.*

Comment: The exact error message is: _Variable " worker" does not exist in /www/sbs.ntsys.se/Symfony/src/NT/SBSServiceBundle/Resources/views/Report/index.html.twig at line 6_. I agree with you that it does't seem to be a twig problem, but i cannot understand why the variable is missing.

Comment: return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index.html.twig',array(
'workers' => $workers
));
and remove the @Template() Annotation

Comment: Still get the same error. I have confirmed that the correct template gets rendered with that code as well. The return statement now looks like this `return $this->render('NTSBSServiceBundle:Report:index.html.twig',array( 'workers' => $workers ));`.

Comment: it gets realy strange here, are you also sure it uses the right controller - action? echo("right controller");exit; befor your return statement.

Comment: I have confirmed that it's the right controller using your example. If i do a print_r() if $workers, the output is as follows. `Array
(
    [0] => NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker Object
        (
            [id:NT\SBSServiceBundle\Entity\Worker:private] => 2
            [name:protected] => Worker 1
            [mail:protected] => worker1@example.com
            [phone:protected] => 123456789
        )

)`

Comment: sorry, then i have no idea. update your question with what you have now, maybe i can than see something..